# How to count .net core Webapi request times;

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET core and I want to count/measure Web API requests response times.
How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also check Microsoft's own product [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core)

Comment: New knowledge! thanks, I just take a look now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AppMetrics](https://github.com/AppMetrics/AppMetrics) package which helps you to record your application metrics like the rate of requests, counting the number of user logins over time, measure the time taken to execute a database query, measure the amount of free memory.

Also, you can visualize the outputs and display them in [Grafana](https://grafana.com/).

Comment: thanks for answer! I mean is want to counting the number of client request Api times,the AppMetrics can do that? thanks again~

Comment: Actually, I don't understand what you want, but here is what AppMetrics can provide for you: https://www.app-metrics.io/

Comment: that's awesone!